# Relationship between SvelteKit PageData and ActionData for form validation

Tags: sveltekit

```js
// +page.svelte

/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
export let data;

/** @type {import('./$types').ActionData} */
export let form;

/** @type {import("svelte/store").Writable<Entity>} */
const entity = writable(form?.entity ?? data.entity);
/** @type {import("svelte/store").Readable<ValidationResult>} */
const validations = derived(entity, e => async validate(e));
```

The above is the pattern I’ve come up to do form validation with SvelteKit. I bind form elements to the `$entity` store, regardless if it was populated from the page data or the form action. The `form?.entity ?? data.entity` feels a little hacky. (Or maybe just clever?)

It seems to work, but is this going to cause problems? Should I be thinking about it differently?

Comment: Personally, I try to use native form validation as much as possible. Less code, accessible by default.

Comment: The built-in HTML validations are handy, but not very expressive. They can’t do things like checking against the backend if a field value is unique. Belt and suspenders.